# Linear Regression and finding Correlation Coefficient

Tags: probability, statistics, regression, correlation, regression-analysis

In a Simple Linear Regression $y= \alpha + \beta x + \epsilon $, we gather this information:

$S_y=20, S_x=5,  \widehat{\beta} = 0.2 $

how I could find Instance Correlation Coefficient between x and y?

I ran into this problem for gathering some information in my Research.

Comment: There is a relation between $r, \hat \beta, S_y, S_x$. Look it up in your course notes and use it.

Comment: @HansEngler, it doesn't mentioned by this abstract note. I confused !

Comment: do you have a book or course notes?

Comment: @HansEngler, it's wrote by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relation
$$
\hat \beta = \frac{rS_y}{S_x}
$$
implies that $0.2 = 4r$ and therefore $r = 0.05$.

Comment: is it possible to add a bit detail?‌how u use this formula?‌I accept it/

Comment: ?????????????????